# How to change DataTable when user has open the mail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have Modifiy my code and now I am sending an inline image with the content id in which random Unique id will be generated and stored in database.

```
SMTPMessage message = new SMTPMessage(session);
            MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart("related");
            String cid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();            
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            InternetAddress[] recipientAddress = new InternetAddress[recipientList.length];
            int counter = 0;
            for (String recipient : recipientList) {
                recipientAddress[counter] = new InternetAddress(recipient.trim());
                counter++;
            }

            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, recipientAddress);
            message.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress("tanisha@boolment.com")});
            message.setSubject("News Letters");
            textPart.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To", "tanishaa32@gmail.com");
            textPart.setContent("<html>" + body + "</html>", "text/html");
            MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();  
            imagePart.setContentID("<img src='teapot.jpg?'" + cid + " width='1px' height='1px'>");
            imagePart.attachFile("C:\\Users\\TANISHA AGARWAL\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EmailMarketing\\build\\web\\resources\\teapot.jpg");
            imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
            imagePart.setHeader("Content-Id", cid);
            LOG.info("=========================================" + textPart.getContentID());
            content.addBodyPart(textPart);
            content.addBodyPart(imagePart);
            message.setContent(content);
            Transport.send(message);
            String Status;
            int Delievered;
            int opened;
            int clicked;
            int counters = 0;
            LOG.info("Notify Message is :" + SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS);
            if (SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS == 1) {
                Status = "Sent";
                Delievered = 1;
                opened = 0;
                clicked = 0;
//                for (int i = 0; i > counters; i++) {
//                    Delievered = i;
//                    LOG.info("Delievered: " + Delievered);
//                    counters++;
//                }
            } else {
                LOG.info("------------------------------------");
                Status = "Failed";
                Delievered = 0;
                opened = 0;
                clicked = 0;
            }
```

I have made a column name open in my database which is initially set to 0 but when user open the mail I want that it should be updated to how many times user has open the mail.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a web application that handles the requests for the hidden image, extracts information from the URL about the original message, and updates the database.

Note that some mailers won't display such images by default so this method is only an approximation at best.

Comment: What kind of web Applications?? And I don't know how to extract information from url.....When I print in LOG it gives the same information except user has been change to who is sending mail and recipients has been change to who is recieveing mail.

Comment: A servlet, for example.  The hidden image has to be in the html body.  The Content-ID you’re setting above won’t do anything.  The image URL points to your web application, which gets invoked when the mail reader tries to fetch the image to display it.  You can include query parameters on the image URL that identifies the original message so you can find it in your database.

Comment: Okay....I have now modified that contentid portion and passing an image name with cid that I am generating above....So will it be good enough to send data like that and if yse.....How would I know that gmail have recieved cide that I am sending.

Comment: You don’t know when gmail receives it, you know when someone reads it in their mail reader.  You know because the mail reader fetches the image using the URL you include.  You know the URL is being fetched because you write the web application that responds to the fetch of the URL.

Comment: Suppose I am seding mail to myself and I have read that mail....now as a developer how do I know that cid has been fetched after opening the mail...and I am not storing any cid in my database.

Comment: I'm sorry, you just don't seem to be getting it, and I don't know how else to explain it.  You know the cid has been fetched because when the mail reader fetches http://your.host.name/your-servlet/hidden-image.jpg?cid=123, your servlet running on your.host.name looks at the URL and sees "cid=123".

Comment: Thanks.....for the help Now I am able to track my mail when they have been opened....